# プログラムの実行速度をあげたい

Tags: python, keras

現在リアルタイムにサーマルカメラで撮影し取得した画像に対し，keras-yolo3というpythonの物体検出ライブラリを用いて物体検出を行うことを考えています．

サーマルカメラで撮影し，画像を取得したらその画像を保存するというプログラムを実行したところ，1秒に約10～11枚の画像が出力されました(FPS平均は約10)．

ここに取得した画像をkeras-yolo3で読み込み，検出結果を出力するようにプログラムを書き換えて実行したところ，1枚の画像に対して物体検出に約10秒かかってしまいました(FPS平均は約0.1)．

目標としては，10枚の画像に対して1秒で物体検出を行えるようにしたいのですが，処理速度を上げるにはどうすればいいでしょうか．

#### 環境

Windows10
Anaconda 64bit
Python 3.6.6
GPU: GeForce RTX 2060 (Computer Capability : 7.5)
CUDA 10.0
cuDNN 7.4
tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1
keras 2.2.4
numpy 1.16.4

#### 参考

- [keras-yolo3 GitHub](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3)
- [keras-yolo3を使ってリアルタイム物体検出を簡単に試してみる](https://arakan-pgm-ai.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/20/090000)
- [keras-yolo3で独自データセットの学習方法](https://sleepless-se.net/2019/06/21/how-to-train-keras%E2%88%92yolo3/)

#### ソースコード

物体検出のプログラム(といってもyolo.pyの中身を少し修正したもの)

```
import colorsys
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Input
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
from yolo3.model import yolo_eval, yolo_body, tiny_yolo_body
from yolo3.utils import letterbox_image
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

from time import time

class YOLO(object):
    _defaults = {
        "model_path": 'model_data/trained_nose.h5',
        "anchors_path": 'model_data/yolo_anchors.txt',
        "classes_path": 'model_data/my_classes_nose.txt',
        "score" : 0.3,
        "iou" : 0.45,
        "model_image_size" : (416, 416),
        "gpu_num" : 1,
    }

    @classmethod

    def get_defaults(cls, n):
        if n in cls._defaults:
            return cls._defaults[n]
        else:
            return "Unrecognized attribute name '" + n + "'"


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(self._defaults)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.class_names = self._get_class()
        self.anchors = self._get_anchors()
        self.sess = K.get_session()
        self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes = self.generate()


    def _get_class(self):
        classes_path = os.path.expanduser(self.classes_path)
        with open(classes_path) as f:
            class_names = f.readlines()
        class_names = [c.strip() for c in class_names]
        return class_names


    def _get_anchors(self):
        anchors_path = os.path.expanduser(self.anchors_path)
        with open(anchors_path) as f:
            anchors = f.readline()
        anchors = [float(x) for x in anchors.split(',')]
        return np.array(anchors).reshape(-1, 2)


    def generate(self):
        model_path = os.path.expanduser(self.model_path)
        assert model_path.endswith('.h5'), 'Keras model or weights must be a .h5 file.'
        num_anchors = len(self.anchors)
        num_classes = len(self.class_names)
        is_tiny_version = num_anchors==6
        try:
            self.yolo_model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
        except:
            self.yolo_model = tiny_yolo_body(Input(shape=(None,None,3)), num_anchors//2, num_classes) \
                if is_tiny_version else yolo_body(Input(shape=(None,None,3)), num_anchors//3, num_classes)
            self.yolo_model.load_weights(self.model_path) # make sure model, anchors and classes match
        else:
            assert self.yolo_model.layers[-1].output_shape[-1] == \
                num_anchors/len(self.yolo_model.output) * (num_classes + 5), \
                'Mismatch between model and given anchor and class sizes'
        #print('{} model, anchors, and classes loaded.'.format(model_path))

        hsv_tuples = [(x / len(self.class_names), 1., 1.)
                      for x in range(len(self.class_names))]
        self.colors = list(map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), hsv_tuples))
        self.colors = list(
            map(lambda x: (int(x[0] * 255), int(x[1] * 255), int(x[2] * 255)),
                self.colors))
        np.random.seed(10101)
        np.random.shuffle(self.colors)
        np.random.seed(None)

        self.input_image_shape = K.placeholder(shape=(2, ))
        if self.gpu_num>=2:
            self.yolo_model = multi_gpu_model(self.yolo_model, gpus=self.gpu_num)
        boxes, scores, classes = yolo_eval(self.yolo_model.output, self.anchors,
                len(self.class_names), self.input_image_shape,
                score_threshold=self.score, iou_threshold=self.iou)
        return boxes, scores, classes


    def detect_image(self, image, t_start, num):

        image = image.convert('RGB')

        t = time()
        pass_time = t - t_start
        print("yolo_time_3: ",pass_time)

        if self.model_image_size != (None, None):
            assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
        else:
            new_image_size = (image.width - (image.width % 32),
                              image.height - (image.height % 32))
            boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, new_image_size)

        t = time()
        pass_time = t - t_start
        print("yolo_time_4: ",pass_time)

        image_data = np.array(boxed_image, dtype='float32')
        image_data /= 255.
        image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)
        out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
            [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
            feed_dict={
                self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
                self.input_image_shape: [image.size[1], image.size[0]],
                K.learning_phase(): 0
            })

        font = ImageFont.truetype(font='font/FiraMono-Medium.otf',
                    size=np.floor(3e-2 * image.size[1] + 0.5).astype('int32'))
        thickness = (image.size[0] + image.size[1]) // 300

        t_l_b_r = []

        t = time()
        pass_time = t - t_start
        print("yolo_time_5: ",pass_time)

        for i, c in reversed(list(enumerate(out_classes))):
            predicted_class = self.class_names[c]
            box = out_boxes[i]
            score = out_scores[i]

            label = '{} {:.2f}'.format(predicted_class, score)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
            label_size = draw.textsize(label, font)

            top, left, bottom, right = box
            top = max(0, np.floor(top + 0.5).astype('int32'))
            left = max(0, np.floor(left + 0.5).astype('int32'))
            bottom = min(image.size[1], np.floor(bottom + 0.5).astype('int32'))
            right = min(image.size[0], np.floor(right + 0.5).astype('int32'))
            t_l_b_r.append(top)
            t_l_b_r.append(left)
            t_l_b_r.append(bottom)
            t_l_b_r.append(right)
            #print(t_l_b_r)
            print(label, (left, top), (right, bottom))

            if top - label_size[1] >= 0:
                text_origin = np.array([left, top - label_size[1]])
            else:
                text_origin = np.array([left, top + 1])

            for i in range(thickness):
                draw.rectangle([left + i, top + i, right - i, bottom - i],outline=self.colors[c])

            draw.rectangle([tuple(text_origin), tuple(text_origin + label_size)],fill=self.colors[c])
            draw.text(text_origin, label, fill=(0, 0, 0), font=font)
            del draw

        t = time()
        pass_time = t - t_start
        print("yolo_time_6: ",pass_time)

        result = np.asarray(image)
        result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

<検出結果を表示，保存します>

        cv2.namedWindow("result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("result", result)  
        cv2.imwrite("d:/study_data/image_'+format(num)+'.bmp",result)

        return t_l_b_r

    def close_session(self):
        self.sess.close()
```

メインのプログラム

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
from yolo_ex import YOLO

import sys
import argparse

~~~~~

関係ない箇所については省略させていただきます

~~~~~

<yolo.video.py から拾ってきました>

FLAGS = None
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--model_path', type=str,help='path to model weight file, default ' + YOLO.get_defaults("model_path"))
parser.add_argument('--anchors_path', type=str,help='path to anchor definitions, default ' + YOLO.get_defaults("anchors_path"))
parser.add_argument('--classes_path', type=str,help='path to class definitions, default ' + YOLO.get_defaults("classes_path"))
parser.add_argument('--gpu_num', type=int,help='Number of GPU to use, default ' + str(YOLO.get_defaults("gpu_num")))
parser.add_argument('--image', default=False, action="store_true",help='Image detection mode, will ignore all positional arguments')
parser.add_argument("--input", nargs='?', type=str,required=False,default='./path2your_video',help = "Video input path")
parser.add_argument("--output", nargs='?', type=str, default="",help = "[Optional] Video output path")
FLAGS = parser.parse_args()

<main関数です>

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import cv2
  from time import time

  num = 0

<カメラからデータを取得します>

  t0 = time()

  time_np = np.empty(0)

  while True:

    t = time()
    if num == 0:
        t_start = time()
    pass_time = t - t_start
    print("\n\nyolo_time_1: ",pass_time)

    time_np = np.append(time_np, pass_time)
    t0 = time()

<熱カメラからデータを取得し，輝度値に変換します>    

    image = cam.get_image()
    image = rescale(image)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

<得られた画像にサイズ変換を施します>

    image = add_margin(image,SIZE)

    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    tt = time()
    pass_time2 = tt - t_start
    print("yolo_time_2: ",pass_time2)

<検出プログラムに画像を渡します>

    image_yolo = YOLO.detect_image(YOLO(**vars(FLAGS)), image, t_start, num)

    num += 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

#### どこで時間がかかっているのか

上記のプログラムを動かし，各過程における時間を出力したところ，結果は画像のようになりました．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像を検出プログラム内の関数"detect_image()"に渡す直前から，渡した直後のところで10秒ほどかかっていたので，この部分をどうにかするしかなさそうに見えますが...

Comment: GPUを使えるようにするのが良さそうですね。[keras-yolo3を使った動画の物体検出がすごく遅い。。](https://teratail.com/questions/231254), [IoT カメラの研究開発 - 京都産業大学](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~kano/pdf/study/student/2018SaikiPaper.pdf), [【メモ】KerasでYOLO v3 を動かすまでの設定手順](https://yonesuke0716.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/05/11/120302), [keras-yolo3　学習時にGPUが３％しか使われない](https://teratail.com/questions/281069) GPUの世代・型番の差も大きいらしいですが。

Comment: [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) で試してみるのもひとつの手かも？ (速度の比較など) 参考: [Google Colaboratory上でYOLOを動かして画像認識させてみた](http://kazuki-room.com/i_tried_to_move_yolov3_on_google_colaboratory_to_recognize_the_image/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．まずColabで試してみて，それからGPUについて調べてみることにします．

Comment: `YOLO.generate()` メソッドに `if self.gpu_num>=2:` という条件分岐があるのですが、`YOLO._defaults` では `gpu_num: 1` となっています。実行時に `--gpu_num` で GPU 数を指定していますか？

Comment: 実行時は```python seekpro.py```とだけ入力しているのでGPU数は指定していないです..

Comment: そうなりますと GPU を利用していないことになります。現状では GPU が 1 基だけだと思うので、`YOLO._defaults` では `gpu_num: 0` としておいて `YOLO.generate()` では `if self.gpu_num>0:` に変更、その上で `python seekpro.py --gpu_num 1` として実行すると GPU を利用する様になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのライブラリを知らないので一般論ですが、

現在のコードだと一枚画像を処理するたびにモデルを作成してウェイトをロードして... とやっているように見えます。
このモデルの初期化処理はかなり時間がかかります。

特別に内部状態を持っていないモデルは何度でも推論（=物体検出）を行うことができます。
なので、起動時に一度だけモデルを作成し、以後の無限ループ部分ではそのモデルを使いまわすことができるはずです。

モデルが状態を持っていた場合でも、状態だけをリセットする方法がないか探してみてはどうでしょうか。

---

追記

[detect_video](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/e6598d13c703029b2686bc2eb8d5c09badf42992/yolo.py#L172) 関数が、やろうとしていることに非常に近いと思います。
この関数は動画ファイルを入力としていますが、ファイル190行目で動画から1枚画像を取り出して、それを192行目で `yolo.detect_image` に渡しています。
この `yolo` インスタンスは無限ループの中で再作成されていません。
190行目の処理を `cam.get_image()` に入れ替えて、画像形式の変換も適切に行えば期待通りの動きをすると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．おそらくそのような現象が発生していると思います．もともとkeras-yolo3が，オフラインの画像1枚，もしくは動画1つを入力として，検出を行う感じだったので...．さっそく調べたいのですが，何かいい参考資料があれば教えていただけないでしょうか．

Comment: 返信遅くなりすいません．detect_video関数でdetect_image関数を呼び出す方法を用いたところ，フレームレートが4～5fpsまで上昇し，理想の10fpsには届かなかったものの，リアルタイムでの物体検出に差し支えないレベルで快適になりました．ありがとうございました!